# Display the first post's comments of category in comments.php template

Tags: posts, categories, comments, templates

I want the display the comments from first post of the category only.

Example;

Category
- Post 1 (2 comments)
- Post 2 (1 comments)
- Post 3 (5 comments)

If I am reading the **Post 2** or **Post 3**, I should see **2 comments** of the first post.

How can I code this from template files?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Are these different categories? It is not clear if `Category Post 1` is a category or a post name... Please, [edit] the Question itself for clarifications.

Comment: thanks for correction. I updated the entry. There is 1 category and 3 posts under this category.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I should change the current post object in comments.php with the first post of the category. how can I do this or in any other ways is appreciated.